# Prevent Render.com Server from Sleeping

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, ping

I have hosted a node server on render.com on a free tier. It goes to sleep every 15 minutes, so to prevent that I think I can self ping the server to keep it awake.

I have tried this code but it does not seem to keep the server awake:

```
const cronjob = require('node-cron')
const ping = require('ping')

cronjob.schedule('*/10 * * * *', () => {
    ping.sys.probe("https://servername.onrender.com");
 });
```

How can I achieve this? Is there any other way that I can keep the server awake? I had previously used Kaffeine for Heroku servers. Is there any alternative for Render?

Comment: Render.com is not Heroku. Please don't use the Heroku tag for non-Heroku platforms.

Comment: Why are you passing a URL to `probe` when the documentation says it takes a hostname?

Comment: maybe just add some cronjob yourself by `crontab -e` instead of using node for such a simple task? like ... `*/10 * * * * wget -qO- https://servername.onreader.com &> /dev/null`  or `*/10 * * * * wget -O/dev/null ...` or something?

Answer (score -2):

Please use axios or other module to send http request to the server , it will keep server on